# Sending an Outlook 2010 email from Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to send an email through Outlook 2010 with Python. The email sends properly but I get the following error. What could be causing it:

Error:

```
newMail.send()
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

My code:

```
import win32com.client
olMailItem = 0x0
obj = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
newMail = obj.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = "My Subject"
newMail.Body = "My Body"
newMail.To  = "Example@gmail.com"
newMail.send()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a typo in your call, try this:

```
newMail.Send()
```

Comment: is the typo the capitalization?

Comment: Yes, I should have been more specific.